# Quarkus/vertx: How to get both the parsed request payload and the raw request's inputstream?

Tags: quarkus, vert.x

I tried this:

```kotlin
    @POST
    @Path("/path")
    @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun endpoint(
        body: MyEntity,
        @Context context: ServerRequestContext,
    ): RestResponse<String> {
        val rawInputStream = context.inputStream
        rawInputStream.reset()
        val fullPayload = rawInputStream.readAllBytes().toString(UTF_8)
        // …
    }
```

This works pretty well in a unit test, albeit the need for `reset` because the stream has already been consumed. But it fails in integration tests because the stream is `closed`.
I looked at the [context objects](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#accessing-context-objects) I could be using, but nothing seems to be what I need. Neither `HttpServerRequest` is providing direct access to the stream.

As you might have guessed, our codebase is not reactive.

I want both because this is an endpoint to consume a webhook from a provider with poor documentation, and I will need to build the entity object empirically.

Answer (score 0):

I have something that works but that I dislike a lot:

```kotlin
@Provider
class RawRequestProvider : ReaderInterceptor {
    override fun aroundReadFrom(context: ReaderInterceptorContext?): Any? {
        val inputStream = context?.inputStream!!
        val payload = inputStream.readAllBytes().toString(UTF_8)
        context.inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(payload.toByteArray(UTF_8))
        val entity = context.proceed()

        return entity?.let {
            when (entity) {
                is MyEntity -> {
                    entity.requestPayload = payload
                    entity
                }

                else -> entity
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and so I added

```kotlin
var requestPayload: String?
```

to `MyEntity`.

But then this runs for ALL writers. I'd rather have a usable `ServerRequestContext` in my endpoint.